# Looping while receiving data from async request module

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, request-promise, asynchronous-javascript

I am a newbie in Node.JS. I am trying to fetch data from an api and filtering out data from a miscellaneous response. But my while loop is getting into infinite loop as the res array never gets populated due asynchronous behavior of request.

```
let res=[];
    while(res.length<=10){
        request(searchLink.apiLink, (err, response, body)=>{
            console.log("Agregation complete!");
            if(err){
                throw new Error("Api response error detected : ", err);
            }else{
                body=JSON.parse(body);
                for(let i=0; i<body.results.length; i++){
                    var cond=body.results[i].title!=null && body.results[i].description!=null && body.results[i].content!=null && body.results[i].language=="english";
                    if(cond) res.push(body.results[i]);
                }
                searchLink.apiLink+=`&page=${body.nextPage}`;
            }
        });
    }
```

Promisifying and awaiting is not quite solving the problem as express wants standard functions for middleware and not promises. And as far as I know top level await should be allowed to settle the request but Node is throwing syntax errors.

Comment: `express wants standard functions`   `async` functions are standard functions, the only difference is they return a promise, and you can use them in middleware's in expresss.

Comment: I mean express.use() isn't taking in any promises for arguments. So i have to settle the request operation within each iteration. How?

Comment: What do you mean `expess.use` isn't taking any promises as arguments,..  This will work  ->  `express.use(async (req, res, next) => { .... await something().. etc `

Comment: But I do have to settle them somewhere right? await isn't settling the promises passed on from middle ware to middleware. await can resolve and res.send the settled promise from async functions right?

Comment: The middlewares pass along using the `next` callback,  you have full control of this. eg.. `app.use(async (req, res, next) =>  { await doSomthing(); next(); })`   Pretty much all my express routes use `async / await`, and they work like a charm.

Comment: Exactly the problem is my await doSomething() is throwing syntax error. IDK why. doSomething() is an custom defined async function which contains the code I posted.

Comment: That's fine, you need to trap for errors, just like any other code, something like ->.  `app.use(async (req, res, next) => { try { await doSomething(); next(); } catch (e) { next(e); })`    `next(e)` just passes the error to the next middleware,

Comment: `app.get('/news',(req, res)=>{
    res.send(await settings());
});` This should work right? The settings function is async-ed but the interpreter wont run since await isnt top level of the module or inside a async function.

Comment: `app.get('/news',async (req, res)=>{ res.send(await settings()); })`   Don't forget the `async` or you don't get `await`..

Comment: IT WORKS !! Thanks a lot. Damn 1 async function and the whole code branches off into asyncs. What if I wanted to synchronously run the code after the request ?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean, run the code after the request?.   You maybe need to update question to show an example.  To add `synchronously`  for performance reasons sync code in an express app wants to be kept to the minimal..

Comment: `request` and `request-promise` have been deprecated for many years by the way. You must have seen those in old tutorials. It's best to read more recent materials.

Comment: I started learning JavaScript and node a week ago :( . Long way to go.

Comment: I'd use `fetch` or `axios`, not `request` or `request-promise`.